# How to improve this VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have read and tired many things, but i cant stop this Error 9 every time a cell is changed in range "B2:B26" I was hoping the code would ; when a value is added to a cell in range B2:B26i would look in the cell "A" and open the sheet with the name in cell "A".
It totally works apart from the error 9 comes up every time.
any help woulf be great.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard") 'Name of the primary worksheet
Dim wsName As String
Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B26")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        
For a = 2 To 29
    wsName = sh.Range("A" & a).Value
        'If wsName <> "" Then
        If sh.Range("B" & a).Value <> 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = True
        Else
         If sh.Range("B" & a).Value = 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = False
        'End If
   End If
   End If
Next a
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Error 9, in this case, simply means that there is no such worksheet. So VBA is saying you don't have 28 valid worksheet names in the A column (and you also took out the check on empty strings).

Comment: You might start with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, otherwise your macro might end up calling itself :-)

Comment: @Dominique: Showing or Hiding a sheet doesn't trigger the `Change`-event. And if it would, setting ScreenUpdating  to False wouldn't prevent it - this can be done only by setting `EnableEvents` to false.

Comment: @FunThomas: I agree, but at the end of the macro, the screenupdates are switched on, which looks as iif it has been forgotten to be switched off to start with. In top of that, just a small modification of the macro (setting the value of a single cell) might cause problems if the screenupdates are not switched off.

Comment: Yeah, the first half of your statement is right, just the reason you give for setting ScreenUpdating to False is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(o)** Error 9 ("*Subscript out of range*") happens if you want to access a member of a collection that doesn't exist - in your case you want to show or hide a non-existing sheet. Double-check the content of your data in column A.

**(o)** You can prevent the runtime error 9 by using error handling. The statement `On Error Resume Next` is dangerous because it hides all runtime errors, so limit it only to that statement where you expect a possible error (and handle that error by yourself).

**(o)** As you have your code in the Change-event, you don't have to loop over all possible cells, only the cells that where modified. For this, check the `target`-parameter. To get the name of the sheet of a modified cell in column B, use the `Offset`-function to get the name of the sheet from column A.

**(o)** Also, as you have your code in the Change-event, you don't need to use a worksheet variable. Within the change event, the ActiveSheet is always the sheet that triggered the event.

**(o)** You can shorten the code that shows or hides the sheets.

Your code could look like that:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target  ' Loop over all modified cells
        If Not Intersect(Range("B2:B26"), cell) Is Nothing Then
            ' Something in column B was changed.
            Dim wsName As String
            wsName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value  ' Get sheet name from column A
            If wsName <> "" Then  ' Only if the name column is filled
                On Error Resume Next   ' Begin of manual error handling
                ' Show or hide the sheet
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = (cell.Value <> 0)
                If Err.Number = 9 Then
                    ' Runtime error 9 happened, the sheet does not exist. 
                    MsgBox "Sheet " & wsName & " is not present in this workbook."
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0        ' End of manual error handling
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, this works prefectly and I understand why! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide/Show Sheets

- There always has to be at least one visible sheet (`On Error Goto ClearError`).
- To include charts, you need to use the `Sheets` collection and declare the sheet variable `As Object`.
- If a sheet name is a number, you need to pass the number as a string. Otherwise, it will be treated as a sheet index (`If Not IsError(Value) Then` and `shName = CStr(Value)`).
- If a sheet with a given name doesn't exist, an error will occur (`On Error Resume Next`).

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Target.Worksheet.Range("B2:B26")
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim wsName As String: wsName = Target.Worksheet.Name
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Target.Worksheet.Parent
    
    Dim sh As Object, icell As Range, Value As Variant
    Dim shName As String, HideSheet As Boolean
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        Value = icell.Value
        If IsNumeric(Value) Then ' i.e. zero or empty
            If Value = 0 Then HideSheet = True
        End If
        Value = icell.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            shName = CStr(Value)
            If StrComp(shName, wsName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "You don't want to hide this worksheet.", vbExclamation
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set sh = wb.Sheets(shName)
                On Error GoTo ClearError
                If sh Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "There is no sheet named """ & shName & """!", _
                        vbExclamation
                Else
                    sh.Visible = Not HideSheet
                    Set sh = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        'Else ' error in cell; do nothing
        End If
    Next icell

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```